# The meaning of $f\in C^\infty$ using multi-index notation.

Tags: analysis, functions, definition

For $f:\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb C$, we write $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^N,\mathbb C)$ if $f$ is infinitely partially differentiable.

Using multi-index notation, can I transrate it to

> $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb C)$ if for all multi-index $\alpha$ and $x\in\mathbb R^N$, $\partial^\alpha f(x)$ exists

?

I'm not sure because the books I read doesn't write this expression.

Comment: yes, that's right